# Klein paradox in the massless case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, dirac-equation, graphene

I have a question about the Klein paradox in the massless case, for a potential step of height $V_0$ (this is exactly the situation described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_paradox)). I don't have a problem to understand the "paradox", and I think the Wikipedia's illustration is quite telling.
**My question is**: what append at the limit case $E_0 = V_0$? The "wave function" after the step is constant ($k=0$), and the Dirac equation for the spinor's components $\Psi_1$, $\Psi_2$ become $0 = 0$... Thus there are no conditions for the value of those components. If I choose $\Psi_1 = \Psi_2 = 1$ for example, I still get $T=1$. If I choose $\Psi_1 = -\Psi_2 = 1$, I get $R=1$. I understand this with the fact that at the node the group velocity is not defined.
So what would really happen in real life?

**Edit** : By continuity of $T(E)$ I would say that the good answer is $T=1$. Also if I end the step potential (I take a potential barrier), the electron coming from the left has to pass the barrier, as it can't change its group velocity. So for me $T$ is always $1$, even in the pathological case $E=V_0$.

[image: Illustration of the transmission]

Comment: In real life you have QED so no paradox

Comment: Yes yes of course, but it is not very satisfying. We could imagine to do this kind of experiment with graphene (and I think QED wouldn't be necessary). What would happen then ?

Comment: The experiment has indeed been carried out. In graphene, electrons behave as massless particles and transmission is just 1 (or very high) almost independent of the potential height.